# make new column in dataframe r by assign

Tags: r, assign

I have a dataframe

```
A=data.frame(a=1:4,b=11:14)
> A
  a  b
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
```

and would like to be able to generate a new column based on the original, but would also like to have the name of the column based on them as well.

I would like the end result to be

```
> data.frame(A,ab)
  a  b ab
1 1 11 11
2 2 12 24
3 3 13 39
4 4 14 56
```

I tried

```
> assign(paste(colnames(A)[1],'someText',colnames(A)[2],sep=''),A$a*A$b)
> A
  a  b
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
```

to no avail. The assignation worked though

```
> asomeTextb
[1] 11 24 39 56
```

Note that I have 56 columns, and wanted to make the column names an indication of what I did to the columns, using loops and referencing via i and j. Basically:

```
for(i in 1:n){
    assign(paste(colnames(A)[i],'someText',colnames(A)[i-1],sep=''),A[,i]*A[,i-1])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
A=data.frame(a=1:4,b=11:14)
> A[[paste0(colnames(A)[1],colnames(A)[2])]] <- with(A,a*b)
> A
  a  b ab
1 1 11 11
2 2 12 24
3 3 13 39
4 4 14 56
```

...and forget that you ever *heard* of the function `assign`. Like, never use it again, or even really think about it. It is dead to you.

If you apply this to the `for` loop you sketched, be aware that starting your loop index at 1 and then referencing the column i-1 is going to cause problems. There is no column 0. You probably want to loop from 2 to `n`.

Comment: Could also use the collapse option: `paste(colnames(A)[1:2], collapse="")`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach with `dplyr`

```
A=data.frame(a=1:4,b=11:14)

library(dplyr)

AB = A %>% mutate(ab = a*b)
```